# How to call slim container inside laravel eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, slim, slim-3

I am using slim 3 with laravel eloquent  "illuminate/database": "^5.6",

in my slim code example

define language class in Container

```
$container['language'] = function($container){
    return new \App\Library\Language($container);
};
```

in language class i have function getLanguageId() and this value pass in start application (in this example return language id = 1)

In Model Blog

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Blog extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'blog';
    protected $primaryKey = 'blog_id';

    public function getLanguageId(){
       // I need access to Slim container here
// Example return $container->get('language')->getLanguageId()
// It's possible to do ?
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't touch the container in a Model, it is bad practice.
Create a languageService, add it to the container, and get the lang things through that. You will thank yourself later

Answer (score 0):

Pass the language ID through a constructor:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Blog extends Model
{
    private $lang;

    public function __construct($lang)
    {
        $this->lang = $lang;
    }

    public function getLanguageId()
    {
       return $this->lang;
    }
}
```

Do not fall into a service locator antipattern by depending on a container everwhere. So create your object like this:

```
$lang = $container->get('language')->getLanguageId();
$blog = new Blog($lang);
```

Comment: How to using with static call example Blog::all() ?

Comment: @PeterJack you can do `(new User($lang))->fetchAllRecords()` and include this function `fetchAllRecords` in your model class with `return self::all()`

Comment: Seriously, don't use a static call, it's bad practice.